# drops down opens on menu hover in mobile view

Tags: css, mobile, hover, mousehover

When we switch to mobile view in desktop, the drop down appears on menu hover.
We want to disable the opening of drop down in mobile view.

Though in mobile it doesn't happen , but whenever we change to mobile view in desktop the issue appears.

Any idea how to disable this only in mobile view?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a media query like 767px to hide the menu on certain screens. Also, you can write code for window resizing.